# How do i using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Good day, I'm trying to use socket.io i facing some problem with `404 not found`. I'm using `:84` as my xampp port

Folder structure

```
--tests
     --node_modules
  --app.js
  --index.html
```

Here is my html content

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:84/test/');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });

</script>
```

and this `app.js`

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');

    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

I'm bit confuse about setting this part

```
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:84/test/');
```

and this part

```
app.listen(8080);
```

I'm using windows 7 64 bit and i'm using xampp to run it. When i run it i get 404 error like this

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:84/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Ll8amII"
```

how can i fix it? sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

Comment: try a different port like `9999` and point the script to load from `http://localhost:9999`. Does the nodejs server run in 8080?

Comment: I have change it and still same problems

Comment: Don't forget to restart the server, and refresh the page in the browser after you change the code

Comment: @OmriLuzon the error is gone . Now, how can i check if it's working  ?

Comment: @YVS1102 Look at the console in node and your browser and see the output

Comment: Do you get this error on browser?

Comment: You have started `express` on 8080 and connecting on `84`. It has to be `8080`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting to the wrong port.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:8080'); // CHANGE HERE
socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', {my: 'data' });
});
</script>
```

`XAMPP` has nothing to do with `express`.